# Most efficient data layout for a symmetrical 3d mesh when interpolating nearest 8 vertices to random sampled point on Intel CPU

Tags: c++, caching, image-processing, multidimensional-array, intel

I have a lookup table of 3d data (a 3D RGB lookup table) where I have preset values of f(r,g,b) for each ri, gi, bi (r, g and b not necessarily evenly spaced). n happens to be the same for r g and b in this case.

r1,r2, ...., rn
g1,g2, ...., gn
b1,b2, ...., bn

I need to calculate and store many millions of estimated f(r,g,b) values from any input (r,g,b) image by interpolating between the the f() values of the nearest 8 vertices surrounding r,g,b. The successive input r,g,b values are RGB video pixels and are not particularly predictable. They may be similar but not identical for a few dozen values then change rapidly. Values of R,G,B near the midpoint will typically be more common than very extreme values though. The table of f() values is preset and doesn't change - I can't make assumptions about f() other than the sampling intervals of f() are sufficiently fine that interpolating vertices is a reasonable estimate. I'm targetting higher end Intel CPUs using C++.

Given that the entire table could be large (several MB) and may not fit in the L1 or L2 cache, is there a cache-efficient layout which isn't very expensive to index and keeps 8 neighbouring vertices nearer to each other in memory to make cache misses less likely? Is it likely to perform badly if I'm using the same f() table from multiple threads to increase speed?

My first thought is to use a simple linear C array and calculate an index into it - ftable[r + n *(g + n*b)]

One alternative is to use C style 3d arrays with their multiple lookups - ftable[r][g][b] but it seems likely to perform worse given the relative cheapness of a couple of additions and multiplies for indexing versus the expense of lookups and potential L1/L2 cache misses. Alternatively is there a cunning method of laying out a C style 3D array that improves cache hit rate for looking up 8 neighbouring vertices of an essentially random input value?

Comment: Some random questions:What's the bit depth of the input images?

Comment: If by CPU you mean a CPU chip then a good way is to run OpenCL on the GPU core.

Comment: what do you really want to do? It might be overkill to use such large 3D LUT:s.

Sidenote: Several years ago I briefly loked at color correction with 3D LUT tables.

I don't think any tools I looked at supported creating LUT:s larger then 32*32*32. And even then, most colors would already be interpolated, since the calibration targets available didn't hold 32768 patches. I think it was more common to use 17*17*17 tables, which even then would require 4913 calibration patches, so those lut:s would also contain way more samples than physically measured patches.

Comment: Good question. Input and output depth is 8 10 or 16 but integer

Comment: Re GPU I saw a recipe for use GPU fit trilinear interpolation which looked promising but not sure how practical it is to use GPU in this context

Comment: Really interesting point re color correction LUTs being preinterpolated because of lack of measurement points. On the other hand it's difficult reverse engineer an arbitrary supplied LUT to determine whether some data points aren't relevant without some fiddly and possibly delicate calculations to estimate the linearity of different sections. Also was curious whether better layouts existed even if overkill for smallish LUTs :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the most efficient method, but a KD-Tree would solve your problem pretty efficiently.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

It's easy to implement and is designed for this type of problems.